# Hover state flickers in FF, but not in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, html

heres my example;
http://camoconnell.com/ddu/

im at odds as how to resolve this, im not sure if the problem is restricted to the jquery or the DOM structure.

any suggestions appreciated,
thanks

Comment: the strange thing, is its only problematic on the righthand side. which makes me think its a CSS/HTML problem..

Comment: I love it when people say it's a browser specific problem and then I open it up in another browser and the same problem occurs = I see the same thing happening in Chrome 15

Comment: I think first thing you might wanna do is set the Hover / Link areas (you could change those to `leftside-wrap` and `righttside-wrap`) to be width: 50% and height: 100% Because either side jumps around If the cursor isn't in specific position. (It's not like hovering over one area closes the other area completely.. So, it would work better.)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using such an old version of jQuery ? 1.5.0 ??

Comment: newer version of jquery helped

Comment: Cam, if (in firefox) you move your cursor from the left to right in to the Summer side hover img.. and stop cursor movement right when it starts animating and keep it there. You will notice a `looping` problem. ( Isn't the only scenario that this can happen, but I think easiest to test out. ) You should change your `#rightside-wrap` and `#leftside-wrap` to be the hover elements. That way there would be less chances to get any "looping" problems.. That way you reduce the chances of this sort of jumping from happening.

Comment: ..turns out it was browser related

Comment: Cam, this specific thing I described, wasn't browser specific, but easier to see in firefox..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the 40% rule in front of the 60% rule. Because you have it the other way around, the hovered element is made bigger before the other is made smaller. This resulted in the bigger element no longer fitting next to the small one and being wrapped to underneath it. It is then no longer under the cursor so the hover rule no longer applies. This keeps happening back and forth. So here is the code:

```
$(sidesAr[target]).stop(true,true).animate({width:"40%"},600);
$(this).parent().parent().stop(true,true).animate({width:"60%"},600);
```

Or jQuery 1.7 as it doesn't seem to have any problems with your code.

Comment: thanks for your help Gerben. i rearrange the code and seem's to be purring. also threw in a conditional, which has helped.

Comment: it broke again but found the problem and your right, it was wrapping. chrome manages to animate the parameters in unison, while there was a lag in FF. i ended up applying an overlay, separating content and voiding wrapping. phew 4 agonizing hours

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parent().parent().stop(true,true).animate({width:"60%"},600);
$(sidesAr[target]).stop(true,true).animate({width:"40%"},600);`

Shouldn't it be like :

`$(sidesAr[target]).stop(true,true).animate({width:"60%"},600);
$(sidesAr[other_target]).stop(true,true).animate({width:"40%"},600);`